# Error 403 while scraping a website in python using requests and selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-requests

i am trying to scrape a website "https://coinatmradar.com/" . I am using requests, beautifulsoup and selenium (wherever required) to scrape data. But after a while, my ip got blocked by the website as it was using cloudflare protection.

```
country_url = "https://coinatmradar.com/country/226/bitcoin-atm-united-states/"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
response=requests.get(country_url, headers=headers)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')
```

This is the part of code that i am using. I am getting response 403. Is there other way around to make it work with requests and selenium both?

Comment: You can use IP rotation and captcha resolver as a layer to your scraper to avoid getting blocked. I found this article that helped me handle IP blocking.  
https://medium.com/@scraperguy/this-could-be-the-answer-to-your-web-scraping-problems-66c88e775c42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set your headers like that:

```
headers = {'Cookie':'_gcar_id=0696b46733edeac962b24561ce67970199ee8668', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
```

Comment: i will give it a try. I am also using selenium. What changes for chromedriver should i do to use it without getting blocked?